# UICollectionView cell gets configured too many times

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I noticed that `UICollectionView` calls `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` on its data source quite a few times. For example, on each `layoutSubviews` all cells are "reconfigured", no matter if they were already visible or not.

When `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is called, we're expected to:

> Your implementation of this method is responsible for creating,
>   configuring, and returning the appropriate cell for the given item.
>   You do this by calling the
>   `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method of the
>   collection view and passing the reuse identifier that corresponds to
>   the cell type you want. That method always returns a valid cell
>   object. Upon receiving the cell, you should set any properties that
>   correspond to the data of the corresponding item, perform any
>   additional needed configuration, and return the cell.

The problem is that configuring a cell is not always a cheap operation, and I don't see why I should reconfigure cells that are already configured.

How can we avoid redundant configuration of the cells? Or is there something I'm not understanding correctly?

Comment: Check out collectionView: willDisplayCellAtIndexPath and see if it is called more or fewer times than cellForItemAtIndexPath.  You only really need to use cFIAIP to alloc the cell, wDCAIP is where you should do the actual display logic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can avoid this.  The problem is that **UICollectionView** is so general and FlowLayout isn't the only layout.  Since you are allowed to make crazy layouts, any layout change, like a layoutsubviews, could completely change the layout you want -- a grid in portrait and a triangular arrangement in landscape...  The only way to know what the layout should be is to find out the location and size of each cell.

**UICollection** view is *not* cheap for lots and lots of elements.

Answer (score -1):

Simply after configuring a `cell` just use `cell.tag = 1;` , then next time you can avoid reconfiguring same cell by using `if(!cell.tag)`.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:YourCellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(!cell){
        //Create cell ...
    } 
    if(!cell.tag){
        //Do things you have to do only once
    }
    else{
        //DO things you have to do every time.
    }

    return cell;
}
```